# How to stop localhost from redirecting to live site

Tags: php, joomla, configuration

I have a Joomla local site: `http://localhost:8080/vanderGiesen` but it redirects directly to the live site: `https://www.gitaarschoolvdgiessen.nl/en/`.

I already changed this in the `configuration.php` file:

```
public $tmp_path = '/var/www/vhosts/http://localhost:8080/vanderGiesen/httpdocs/joomla/tmp';
    public $log_path = '/var/www/vhosts/http://localhost:8080/vanderGiesen/httpdocs/joomla/logs';
```

But nothing changed.

I also edited `.htaccess` in the Joomla folder and deleted these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.gitaarschoolvdgiessen\.nl
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.gitaarschoolvdgiessen.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

So what to change, so that the local site will not be redirected to the live version?

Comment: Why did you make the changes that you did to the configuration file?

Comment: HI, at: D:\Xampp\htdocs\vanderGiesen

Answer (score 0):

Change var $host = 'https://www.gitaarschoolvdgiessen.nl/en/'; to var $host = 'localhost'; in configuration.php

Comment: HI, you mean this: public $host = 'localhost'; in the Joomla folder

Comment: Just look at the file, it says literally **on the second line** redirect to the other site.   You need to at least try.

Comment: @LikeToDo I mean in the joomla root folder, inside configuration.php file.
where ever you find $host = 'Your Live URL'; , Just change the value to 'localhost'